# How can I have a partition between function in the same Rscript in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I am writing a large function in R using Rstudio. This function includes different parts that should be separated. I use `cmd+shift+R` to get a tittle for each part. It is helpful but I really need to get a partition as a frame or box. Using `cmd+shift+R`, is only help for a short title.

some code here

partition

title and some description here.

partition

How can I have that partition using a short cut? That is, I need a frame including some information about the following part. How can I do it using Addins in `Rstudio`.

Comment: @jaySf I need it in a frame (box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jaySf proposal seems really useful (or I don't understand what you mean by a "box")

Each comment line with several `-----` or `====` will be considered by Rstudio as a title/section. If you don't want that line to be considered as a section (because it is the "frame" of your box), just end it with `#`.

By the way, I use `# /*` and `# */` to make knitr ignore everything between these tags when I "spin" an R script (Ctrl+Shif+K in R studio)

```
# /* 
# ----------------------------- Title of the section ---------------------------
# */

# =================================================================================  #
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse 
# lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum 
# ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. 
# Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum 
# diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat 
# in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. 
# Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu 
# enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in 
# faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris 
# sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.
# 
# =================================================================================  #


# /*
# ================================================================================= #
# 
# -----------------------------   Other title  -------------------------------  
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse 
# lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum 
# ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. 
# Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum 
# diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat 
# in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. 
# Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu 
# enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in 
# faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris 
# sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.
# 
# =================================================================================  #
# */
#
```

You can automate this in Rstudio via Rstudio addins.

In a few basic steps :

1) Create a new package structure with devtools

```
setwd("~/stats/Rpackages")
devtools::create('MyRstudioAddins')
```

2) Save the following function in an R script called 'insertTitle.R' in the `R` directory of your package

```
#' Insert title and box
#'
#' @export
insertTitle <- function() {
    rstudioapi::insertText("# /* 
# ----------------------------- Title of the section ---------------------------
# */

# =================================================================================  #
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse 
# lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum 
# ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. 
# 
# =================================================================================  #
")
}
```

3) With R, create the `inst/rstudio/addins.dcf` file with the following content (this will be used by R studio to recognize your package as containing addins). Or create the same file manually.

```
dir.create("~/stats/Rpackages/MyRstudioAddins/inst/rstudio", recursive = TRUE)

cat(file = "~/stats/Rpackages/MyRstudioAddins/inst/rstudio/addins.dcf", a^end = TRUE,
"Name: Insert title
Description: Insert title and box
Binding: insertTitle
Interactive: false

")
```

4) Install your package in R

```
install.packages("~/stats/Rpackages/MyRstudioAddins/", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

5) In Rstudio, go to Tools/Modify Keyboard Shortcuts and add the shortcut you like for your command (search "addins" if you can't find it).

See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) for more info on Rstudio addins

NB : as suggested by others breaking a big function in smaller ones is a good idea. But Sections, titles and "boxes" might still be useful to organize your code (with or without functions).

Comment: how did you do that automatically. I only get `-------` line when I use `cmd+shift+r`.

Comment: I need to use `====` automatically.

Comment: @Silver_80 `cat("#----")`?

Comment: To alaborate again on @jaySf comment see the updated answer with Rstudio addins...

Comment: That's a really cool introduction to addins thanks, as I understand once you'll have the addin installed you'll still need to have the function loaded, a clean workaround would be to have a package with your addin functions and have `Binding: your_package::insertTitle` in your `dcf` file, a quick workaround would be to put `insertTitle` in your RProfile, and maybe rename it `.insertTitle` so it doesn't show up with `ls`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper : I know it looks like black magic but in fact you don't need to have the function loaded. Installing the package is enough providing that the `dcf` file is formated as recommended in the documentation...

Answer (score 2):

> ***EDIT***: with updated question I see it doesn't address OP's issue, leaving it here for archive

I suggest you follow Blcknx's advice and rethink your structure.

If you can't, you could split your code using `source`, so you can open the different parts in multiple tabs :

```
# setup
write("x <- 1;print(x)","part1.R") # create a dummy file
write("x <- x+1;print(x)","part2.R")
file.edit("part1.R","part2.R") # will open it in a R studio tab

long_fun <- function(){
  source("part1.R",local=TRUE)
  source("part2.R",local=TRUE)
}

long_fun()
# [1] 1
# [1] 2

x
# Error: object 'x' not found

# clean up
file.remove("part1.R","part2.R")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large function, that you need to structure, I suggest to break it into multiple sub functions. By this you achieve a lot:

- visual separation
- less errors due to limited scope
- you can test each part on it's own
- you can reuse parts
- each sub function get's a descriptive name => less comments
- the parent function tells the whole story in one glance
- you are forced to rethink you code in logical terms
- this leads to better architecture